# Peut attendre ou s'attendre

Tags: usage, verbes-pronominaux

Je me demande si des phrases suivantes ont du sens en français ; le cas échéant quelle est la différence et laquelle est plus adéquate ?

> Le départ peut attendre.
>
> Le départ peut s'attendre.

**EDIT** (d'après les commentaires)

Sens :

Un départ va arriver. Mais je peux décaler le départ pour faire quelque chose d'autre.

Un autre scenario :

> J'ai une conférence et il me faut préparer les diapos et le discours.
> Cependant j'ai dit à mes collègues : la conférence peut attendre ; je
> vais terminer notre projet durant le week-end.

Je me demande si j'étais bien compris. Autrement dit, dans ce contexte (décaler le travail pour la conférence pour faire quelque chose d'autre et pas la conférence elle-même) je ne peut pas dire la conférence peut attendre, métaphoriquement ? Est-ce mieux de dire le travail pour la conférence peut attendre ?

Comment: Quel est le sens attendu ?

Comment: @jlliagre Un départ va arriver. Mais je peux décaler le départ pour faire quelque chose d'autre.

Comment: @jlliagre Un autre scénario.  J'ai une conférence et il me faut préparer les diapos et le discours. Cependant j'ai dit à mes collègues : la conférence peut attendre ;  je vais terminer notre projet durant le week-end. Je me demande si j'étais bien compris.

Comment: Pareil: la conférence pourra commencer plus tard, ce n'est pas le plus important.

Comment: @jlliagre alors dans ce contexte  (décaler le travail pour la conférence pour faire qqch d'autre et pas la conférence elle-même) je ne peut pas dire la conférence peut attendre, metaphoriquement ? Est-ce mieux de dire le travail pour la conférence peut attendre ?

Comment: Si on décale la préparation de la conférence mais que la conférence elle-même n'est pas affectée (pas repoussée), *la conférence peut attendre* n'a guère de sens puisqu'elle ne va pas devoir attendre.

Comment: As Daniel Lavoie tells us, [« Le métro n'attend pas »](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=czmFWP-gw0I) !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seule la première phrase est idiomatique :

> Le départ peut attendre.

Elle signifie que l'on ne se préoccupe pas du retard qu'un départ imminent risque de subir.

En supposant qu'il s'agit du départ d'une course, on pourra dire :

> Il n'y a pas urgence, les coureurs peuvent (ou le public peut) attendre (que le départ soit donné).